# insert an image using JS for specific input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to output a pic of a BMW if the output is Mario, a tesla if the name is Julio, and another care if it is nono of those names. All those cars are store on an array.

I have been trying using document.createElement("image-example"); but haven't get it done.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tesla Likes Pigeons. And so do other people.</title>

    <style>
      /* Basic CSS comment */
      body {
        background: grey;
        color: white;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: black;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #333;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      /* this is an event */
      /* alert("I'm annoying"); */

      var username = prompt("Hello, who are you?");
      var car = new Array("BMW", "Tesla", "fiat");

      if (username === "mario") {
        document.write(
          "<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + car[0] + "!</h1>"
        );
      } else if (username === "julio") {
        document.write(
          "<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + car[1] + "!</h1>"
        );
      } else {
        document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " You didn't win a car!</h1>");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="tesla.jpg" alt="Nic Tesla" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would add an id to that img and use document.getElementById(id).src and .alt to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `document.createElement()` like that. That would just create a new `<image-example></image-example>` element, which is not a valid HTML element (would not display any image). Also you would have to **append** it to the page with `document.body.appendChild()`.

#### Possible solution

It's a bit cumbersome if you keep [repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in your code. So let's create a [**function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) to what I mentioned earlier about `document.createElement()`, so we can reuse that snippet afterwards:

```js
function insertImg(src, alt) {
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = src;
  img.alt = alt;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Second, if you have a limited number of possible strings and an outcome for each one of them, I would suggest that you use [**Javascript objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) instead of arrays.

Like so:

```js
// store a car, an image and an alt text for each possible user
var usersCars = {
  "mario": {
    car: 'BMW',
    src: "bmw.jpg",
    alt: "BMW"
  },
  "julio": {
    car: 'Tesla',
    src: "tesla.jpg",
    alt: "Nic Tesla"
  }
}
```

Then, for better control, let's use just one if/else block (either the user is found or not).

```js
var username = prompt("Hello, who are you?");

if (usersCars[username]) {
  // the username was recognized
  document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + usersCars[username].car + "!</h1>");
  insertImg(usersCars[username].src, usersCars[username].alt);
} else {
  // no such username
  document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " You didn't win a car!</h1>");
  insertImg('fiat.jpg', 'Oh, what a shame!');
}
```

Lastly, since we're using `document.createElement()` and then `document.body.appendChild()`, we should leave the document's body empty, so it can be populated entirely through Javascript.

#### Result

Here's the full snippet so you can play with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tesla Likes Pigeons. And so do other people.</title>
  <style>
    /* Basic CSS comment */
    
    body {
      background: grey;
      color: white;
      width: 960px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 30px;
      color: black;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-size: 80px;
      color: #333;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    function insertImg(src, alt) {
      let img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      img.alt = alt;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }

    var usersCars = {
      "mario": {
        car: 'BMW',
        src: "bmw.jpg",
        alt: "BMW"
      },
      "julio": {
        car: 'Tesla',
        src: "tesla.jpg",
        alt: "Nic Tesla"
      }
    }

    var username = prompt("Hello, who are you?");

    if (usersCars[username]) {
      // the username was recognized
      document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " you won a " + usersCars[username].car + "!</h1>");
      insertImg(usersCars[username].src, usersCars[username].alt);
    } else {
      // no such username
      document.write("<h1>Hello " + username + " You didn't win a car!</h1>");
      insertImg('fiat.jpg', 'Oh, what a shame!');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, for taking the time to answer my question. It works perfectly, and I was able to understand the logic.

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes. Such as using switch and case instead of if else. and used some helper functions to break down the code into chunks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tesla Likes Pigeons. And so do other people.</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: grey;
        color: white;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: black;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 80px;
        color: #333;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="tesla.jpg" alt="Nic Tesla" />

    <script>
      const name = prompt("Hello, who are you?");
      const car = ["BMW", "Tesla", "fiat"];
      const h1 = (name, car) => `<h1>Hello ${name} you won a ${car}</h1>`;
      const writer = tag => document.write(tag);
      switch (name) {
        case "mario":
          writer(h1(name, car[0]));
          break;
        case "julio":
          writer(h1(name, car[1]));
          break;
        default:
          writer(h1(name, "car"));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was looking at this one; where is the jpg file attached? Thank you, man...

Comment: @MarioGomez Unfortunately I didn't understand your question. "where is the jpg file attached"